# How to move Key Binding method into its own Class?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, key-bindings

I am making a game and have got keybindings working in my GamePanel class. However I want to be able to put my key bindings method in its own separate class, so that other panels of the game can access the method, so I don't have to rewrite it each time. I've moved it over as you can see, but I am getting a null pointer exception on the line that calls the addKeyBinding method. I'm thinking this has something to do with it not knowing what action to call? But I'm not sure. How can I fix this?

GamePanel class:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    // Global Variables
    private Ball ball;
    private Paddle paddle;
    private GameFrame gameFrame;
    private int width;
    private int height; 
    private Timer timer;
    private int brickHeight = 30;
    private int brickWidth = 60;
    ArrayList<Bricks> brickArray = new ArrayList<Bricks>();
    int brickCount;
    int leftOverSpace;
    private int ballXDir = -1;
    private int ballYDir = -2;
    private boolean play = false;
    private int delay = 8;
    private KeyBindings kBindings;

    // create a constructor
    GamePanel (int gamePanelWidth, int gamePanelHeight) {
        this.setWidth(gamePanelWidth);
        this.setHeight(gamePanelHeight);
        initialiseGame();
        this.isVisible();
    }

    private void initialiseGame() {
        play = false;
        ball = new Ball(10, 520, 30, 30, this); //create the ball object
        paddle = new Paddle(this, 50, 700, 100, 10); //creates paddle object
        initialiseBrickArray();
        
        //initialise key bindings for space, left and right
        kBindings.addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, "startBall", (evt) -> {
            play = true;
        });
        kBindings.addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, "moveLeft", (evt) -> {
            paddle.moveLeft();
        });
        kBindings.addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, "moveRight", (evt) -> {
            paddle.moveRight();
        });       
    }
 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }  
}
```

My new KeyBindings class:

```
public class KeyBindings implements ActionListener {

    public void addKeyBinding(JComponent comp, int keyCode, String id, ActionListener actionListener) {
        InputMap im = comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap ap = comp.getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false), id);
        ap.put(id, new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                actionListener.actionPerformed(e);
            }
        });

        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `kBindings` in constructor, or somewhere else, but before you call `kBindings.addKeyBinding`. Just

```
kBindings = new KeyBindings();
```

Comment: This fixes the OPs issue but OP should be aware as per @camickrs answer there is no need for it to be an instance method and could rather be static. +1 nonetheless

Comment: @LiL, *I'm thinking this has something to do with it not knowing what action to call*  - why would you think something like that.  *its so obvious!* - a NullPointerException usually is obvious. The stack trace tells you the line number so all you need to do is find the variable on the line that is null and make sure you have an instance of that object.  So the first thing to do is determine which variable is null. Don't guess which variable is null. This is easily achieved by using a debugger or adding a few System.out.println(...) statement for all the variable on the statement in question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no need for the KeyBindings class to implement ActionListener. You don't actually add an instance of this class to a button as an ActionListener. This is just a class with a convenience method.

You aren't actually changing any property of the KeyBindings class. So this should probably just be a static method of the class:

```
//public void addKeyBinding(...)
public static void addKeyBinding(...)
```

Then you invoke it as:

```
//kBindings.addKeyBinding(...);
KeyBindings.addKeyBinding(...);
```

Comment: This is the better answer there is no need to Instantiate an instance of the class when there is nothing unique to each instance. Infant I did it similary in my `KeyBinder` class of [SwingGameLibrary](https://github.com/davidkroukamp/SwingGameLibrary) I'm currently developing. +1.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Infant I did everything that possible static, until I realized that this is non testable. Of course, just doing `kBindings = new KeyBindings()` also non testable. But this is another topic :)

Comment: I don't think I would be testing a keybinding class for a game... but that's another topic